Keycloak: Multiple authentication methods after login
In Keycloak I am trying to create an authentication flow which requires the user to log in and then let it choose from either the OTP Form Method or the WebAuthn Method.
I must assume that some users have not setup neither OTP nor WebAuthn so the registration form should popup when trying to log in for the first time.
I managed to create a flow which lets the user choose between "login -> otp" or "login -> webAuthn" but the problem here is that the choice for authentication comes before the login. What I would much prefer is that the user logs in (with username password) and then has the choice between the 2FA method.
This is the flow i have created so far:
Keycloak flow
